# Having issue linking c language file in my xcode project

Tags: objective-c, c

I didn't actually used the file in my project yet, just copy it to my project.

My header file:

```
//
//  Algorithm.h
//  Cellular Radar
//
//  Created by Idan Moshe on 15/09/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Netroads. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_DIM 3
#define N 1000000
#define rand1() (rand() / (double)RAND_MAX)
#define rand_pt(v) { v.x[0] = rand1(); v.x[1] = rand1(); v.x[2] = rand1(); }

struct kd_node_t {
    int trapID;
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    struct kd_node_t *left, *right;
};

int visited;
struct kd_node_t allTraps[1000];


inline double theDistance(struct kd_node_t *a, struct kd_node_t *b, int dim);
static void swap(struct kd_node_t *x, struct kd_node_t *y);
struct kd_node_t* find_median(struct kd_node_t *start, struct kd_node_t *end, int idx);
struct kd_node_t* make_tree(struct kd_node_t *t, int len, int i, int dim);
void theNearest(struct kd_node_t *root, struct kd_node_t *nd, int i, int dim, struct kd_node_t **best, double *best_dist);
void getCloseTrap_KD_TREE(void);


@interface Algorithm : NSObject


@end
```

**EDIT:**

I changed the name of the objects 'dist' and 'nearest', I get the following issue:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_theDistance", referenced
>   from:
>         _theNearest in KDTree.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

**EDIT 2:**

```
//
//  Algorithm.m
//  Cellular Radar
//
//  Created by Idan Moshe on 15/09/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Netroads. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Algorithm.h"

@implementation Algorithm

inline double theDistance(struct kd_node_t *a, struct kd_node_t *b, int dim)
{
    double t, d = 0;
    while (dim--) {
        t = a->x[dim] - b->x[dim];
        d += t * t;
    }
    return d;
}

static void swap(struct kd_node_t *x, struct kd_node_t *y)
{
    double tmp[MAX_DIM];
    memcpy(tmp,  x->x, sizeof(tmp));
    memcpy(x->x, y->x, sizeof(tmp));
    memcpy(y->x, tmp,  sizeof(tmp));
}

/* see quickselect method */
struct kd_node_t* find_median(struct kd_node_t *start, struct kd_node_t *end, int idx)
{
    if (end <= start) return NULL;
    if (end == start + 1)
        return start;


    struct kd_node_t *p, *store, *md = start + (end - start) / 2;
    double pivot;
    while (1) {
        pivot = md->x[idx];

        swap(md, end - 1);
        for (store = p = start; p < end; p++) {
            if (p->x[idx] < pivot) {
                if (p != store)
                    swap(p, store);
                store++;
            }
        }
        swap(store, end - 1);

        /* median has duplicate values */
        if (store->x[idx] == md->x[idx])
            return md;

        if (store > md) end = store;
        else        start = store;
    }
}

struct kd_node_t* make_tree(struct kd_node_t *t, int len, int i, int dim)
{
    struct kd_node_t *n;

    if (!len) return 0;

    if ((n = find_median(t, t + len, i))) {
        i = (i + 1) % dim;
        n->left  = make_tree(t, n - t, i, dim);
        n->right = make_tree(n + 1, t + len - (n + 1), i, dim);
    }
    return n;
}

void theNearest(struct kd_node_t *root, struct kd_node_t *nd, int i, int dim,
                struct kd_node_t **best, double *best_dist)
{
    double d, dx, dx2;

    if (!root) return;
    d = theDistance(root, nd, dim);
    dx = root->x[i] - nd->x[i];
    dx2 = dx * dx;

    visited ++;

    if (!*best || d < *best_dist) {
        *best_dist = d;
        *best = root;
    }

    /* if chance of exact match is high */
    if (!*best_dist) return;

    if (++i >= dim) i = 0;

    theNearest(dx > 0 ? root->left : root->right, nd, i, dim, best, best_dist);
    if (dx2 >= *best_dist) return;
    theNearest(dx > 0 ? root->right : root->left, nd, i, dim, best, best_dist);
}

void getCloseTrap_KD_TREE(void)
{
//    int i;
    struct kd_node_t wp[] =
    {
        {1, {2, 3}}, {1, {5, 4}}, {1, {9, 6}}, {1, {4, 7}}, {1, {8, 1}}, {1, {7, 2}}
    };

    struct kd_node_t searchPoint = {1, {9, 2}};
    struct kd_node_t *root, *found;
//    struct kd_node_t *million;
    double best_dist;

    root = make_tree(wp, sizeof(wp) / sizeof(wp[1]), 0, 2);


    visited = 0;
    found = 0;
    theNearest(root, &searchPoint, 0, 2, &found, &best_dist);

    printf(">> WP tree\nsearching for (%g, %g)\n"
           "found (%g, %g) dist %g\nseen %d nodes\n\n",
           searchPoint.x[0], searchPoint.x[1],
           found->x[0], found->x[1], sqrt(best_dist), visited);

    NSLog(@">> WP tree\nsearching for (%g, %g)\nfound (%g, %g) dist %g\nseen %d nodes\n\n", searchPoint.x[0], searchPoint.x[1], found->x[0], found->x[1], sqrt(best_dist), visited);
    /*
    million = calloc(N, sizeof(struct kd_node_t));
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) rand_pt(million[i]);

    root = make_tree(million, N, 0, 3);
    rand_pt(searchPoint);

    visited = 0;
    found = 0;
    theNearest(root, &searchPoint, 0, 3, &found, &best_dist);

    printf(">> Million tree\nsearching for (%g, %g, %g)\n"
           "found (%g, %g, %g) dist %g\nseen %d nodes\n",
           searchPoint.x[0], searchPoint.x[1], searchPoint.x[2],
           found->x[0], found->x[1], found->x[2],
           sqrt(best_dist), visited);

//    search many random points in million tree to see average behavior.
//     tree size vs avg nodes visited:
//     10      ~  7
//     100     ~ 16.5
//     1000        ~ 25.5
//     10000       ~ 32.8
//     100000      ~ 38.3
//     1000000     ~ 42.6
//     10000000    ~ 46.7

    int sum = 0, test_runs = 100000;
    for (i = 0; i < test_runs; i++) {
        found = 0;
        visited = 0;
        rand_pt(searchPoint);
        theNearest(root, &searchPoint, 0, 3, &found, &best_dist);
        sum += visited;
    }
    printf("\n>> Million tree\n"
           "visited %d nodes for %d random findings (%f per lookup)\n",
           sum, test_runs, sum/(double)test_runs);

    // free(million);
     */
}

@end
```

Comment: nobody ain't no eyes to read that screenie. post text.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a screenshot.


Comment: It seems you have forgot to add those classes/files to your project, at least they are not being linked or compiled.

Comment: 'Compile Sources' - all files are there, i use them in my project all the time.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your source? What is `_theDistance` or `dist`? I don't see either of those in the code above.

Comment: I added the rest of the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you are literally mixing Objective-C and C:

```
@implementation Algorithm

... 

struct kd_node_t* find_median(struct kd_node_t *start, struct kd_node_t *end, int idx)
{

...

@end
```

You only use `@interface` and `@implementation` if you are creating an Objective-C object, not when writing "C that can use Objective-C".  So either create an object or dump the use of `@interface` and `@implementation`.

Comment: I removed the '@implementation' and '@interface' and tried to call the function 'getCloseTrap_KD_TREE();' from AppDelegate and got "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_getCloseTrap_KD_TREE", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"